# How to determine next insert id value (inside a transaction) before actually inserting a new record?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a table with an id column (Autoincrement). How to get the value of the next insert id before actually inserting a new record in the same transaction?

Comment: What driver are you using to conect to the database? Mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: I'm using PDO to connect

Comment: Why do you need to know the next insert id? This sounds like it might be an https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Bill Yes, I have a different problem. After rethinking, I don't think I need to do this (calculate next id before insertion). Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this query:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME) = ('mydatabase', 'mytable');
```

(Of course you would name your database and table, I just used examples.)

This would give you the next auto-increment value *at the moment you run that query*. But in the next instant, some other client could insert a row, causing that id to be used. So the result you value can be wrong almost as soon as you query it.

You could prevent concurrent inserts by [locking your table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html), but most people prefer not to do that, because it blocks concurrent operations.

Other than that, the only way to guarantee you know the next auto-increment value in advance is to execute the INSERT, then query `LAST_INSERT_ID()` or a similar function provided by your connector. For example, [PDO::lastInsertId()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).